# Adding to ReSharper's 'Related Files' list

Tags: resharper, resharper-5.0

From version 5.0 onwards, ReSharper offers a ["Go To Related Files" navigation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Related_Files.html) which offers a list of files that R# thinks are related to the file currently being edited: for example, base types, derived types, `.designer.cs` to and from the relevant `.cs`, and so on.

I have looked in the R# Options and also online, but have not been able to find out:

Is there a way to add files to this list, either within R# natively or by an already-existing plug-in?

(My motivation is to be able to navigate at coding time between files containing classes that are connected by a *run-time-only* convention-over-configuration, er, convention)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about existing plugins, but this feature is extendable.
You need to implement IRelatedFilesProvider interface in your plugin and mark it by RelatedFilesProvider attribute. As far as I know, NHibernate plugin do it for analogous task.

Comment: Is there anything else that is required to get this to run? The attribute requires a type and there doesn't seem to be a tutorial on this.